# Telerik MVC grid custom command not rebinding JSON

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller, telerik

I've got a Telerik grid with a custom command button, which should COPY a row. The command button calls a JsonResult controller method. It copies the line and returns the model but the grid doesn't change - because it's not rebinding, I think.

I thought it would happen automagically.

```
Html.Telerik().Grid<MerchantPageModel>()
          .Name("PageChooserGrid")
          .DataKeys(keys => keys
                                .Add(c => c.PageID)
                                .RouteKey("PageID"))
          .Columns(cols =>
              {
                  cols.Bound(c => c.Name).Width(300).ClientTemplate("<input type='text' name='name' value='<#= Name #>' readonly='true' />");
                  cols.Bound(c => c.Template).Width(400).ClientTemplate("<input type='text' name='template' value='<#= Template #>' readonly='true' />");
                  cols.Bound(c => c.Author).Width(100).ClientTemplate("<input type='text' name='author' value='<#= Author #>' readonly='true' />");
                  cols.Bound(c => c.ModifiedDate).Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}").Width(120).ClientTemplate("<input type='text' name='modifieddate' value='<#= ModifiedDate #>' readonly='true' />");
                  cols.Bound(c => c.IncludeInNav).ClientTemplate("<input type='checkbox' name='IncludeInNav' value='<#= IncludeInNav #>' <#= populateCheckboxes(IncludeInNav) #>'  />")
                      .Title("Include In Nav")
                      .Width(100);
                  cols.Command(commands =>
                      {
                          commands.Edit().ButtonType(GridButtonType.Text);
                          commands.Custom("Copy").Text("Copy").DataRouteValues(route => route.Add(o => o.PageID).RouteKey("PageID")).Ajax(true)
                              .Action("_AjaxCopyPage", "SetupWizard");
                          commands.Delete().ButtonType(GridButtonType.Text);
                      }).Title("Action List");
              })
          .DataBinding(data => data.Ajax()
                                   .Select("_AjaxBinding", "SetupWizard")
                                   .Update("_AjaxEditing", "SetupWizard")
                                   .Delete("_AjaxDelete", "SetupWizard"))
          .Pageable()
          .Sortable()
          .ClientEvents(events =>
              { events.OnComplete("Grid_onComplete");
                  events.OnCommand("Grid_onCommand");
                  events.OnDataBound("Grid_OnDataBound");
                  events.OnDataBinding("Grid_OnDataBinding");
              })
              .EnableCustomBinding(true)
          .Render();
```

And the controller returns:

```
   return Json(pageModel.Pages, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should call

```
var grid = $('#PageChooserGrid').data('tGrid');
grid.rebind();
```

after your custom command executed in javascript.

This forces grid to rebind.

Comment: I've found what it does is call the .Select bind event which goes and gets the data from the DB again. It doesn't use the JSON result which I passed back with the copied row, it overwrites it.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the OnComplete method.

```
events.OnComplete("Grid_OnComplete");
```

and your JS code should look like this

```
function Grid_OnComplete(e) {
if (e.name == "copy") {
    $("#" + e.currentTarget.id).data("tGrid").dataBind(e.response.data);
}
```

}

We have a bunch of common custom functions across our grids and attach to the event like so.

```
var bindGridComplete = function ($grid) {
$grid.on('complete', function (e) {
    if (e.name == "copy") {
        $("#" + e.currentTarget.id).data("tGrid").dataBind(e.response.data);
    }
});
```

};